# É possível personalizar o botão de curtir do Facebook?

Tags: html, css, facebook

É possível, eu criar um botão de curtir do facebook personalizado? Quero que quando eu clique no meu botão personalizado (https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8kh8.png) aconteça exatamente o mesmo que aconteceria se eu clicasse no botão padrão de curtir do facebook. Se sim, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: sim, e possivel

Answer (score 2):

Claro que sim. 
Podes por exemplo arranjar duas imagens, com fundos diferentes, e quando detectares o evento click mudas a imagem. Penso que esta será a abordagem mais fácil, no entanto existem outras possiveis.

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso?

Comment: Claro.
Imagino que seja para uma página web certo?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo, certo!

Comment: Então pode ser assim:
    <html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
 <script>
  function toogleLikeIcon()
  {
   var sourceImage=document.getElementById("like").getAttribute("src");
   switch(sourceImage)
   {
   case "notLike.png":document.getElementById("like").src="like.png";break;
   default:document.getElementById("like").src="notLike.png";break;
   }
  }
 </script>
 <img id="like" src="notLike.png" onclick="toogleLikeIcon();">

<body>

</html>

Comment: Podes fazer um Jsfiddle?

Comment: @TiagoP.C Nunca fiz. Mas sabes que mais? Vou tentar....

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40672/discussion-between-leandro-rodrigues-and-tiago-p-c).

Answer (score 1):

```
<html> <head> </head> <body> <script> function toogleLikeIcon() { var sourceImage=document.getElementById("like").getAttribute("src"); switch(sourceImage) { case "notLike.png":document.getElementById("like").src="like.png";break; default:document.getElementById("like").src="notLike.png";break; } } </script> <img id="like" src="notLike.png" onclick="toogleLikeIcon();"> <body> </html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1xo09yhc/

```
 <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/1xo09yhc/embed/"></script>
```